# Magic Trackpad 2 as a MIDI controler

Tags: mouse, magic-trackpad, midi

I want to make music with a MagicTrackpad2, keeping it away from interacting with the mouse pointer.

I found this software: [MultiTouchMidi](https://github.com/jeffkaufman/trackpad_synth) that works great with the builtin trackpad of a macbook.

At first, the pointer of the mouse was moving while I was playing music.
This could be solved with an external mouse, and checking the box "Ignore Trackpad when Mouse is plugged in" under Universal Access.

Now, I would like this: MagicTrackpad2 plays MIDI and does not affect the mouse, and the builtin trackpad controls just the mouse.

How can I achieve this ?